# How to Initilize Map with same values in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, set

How to initialize **new Map<number, boolean>()** with the length of another map with same value i.e **true**.

I have one Map name Map1 and another map Map2 new Map<number, boolean>(); Now  i want to add intilize my map2 with the length of map1 and value is default True. Is there a way to do this in inline ? Not want to iterate over map1 and set values in loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `new Map()` construct with `Array.from()` of the original map and JS `Array#map` function. Note that it's still iterating the initial map.

```js
const map1: Map<number, boolean> = new Map<number, boolean>();
map1
  .set(1, true)
  .set(3, false)
  .set(4, false)
  .set(5, true)
  .set(2, false);

let map2: Map<number, boolean> = new Map(
  Array.from(map1).map(([key, value]) => [key, true])
);

console.log(map2);
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-yxgtjm?file=index.ts)